# Normalization (scaling) in R

Tags: r, normalization, scaling

I am currently analyzing data "train" containing 20 independent variables (as columns). I am trying to normalize column 2 to 11 of this data to zero mean and variance = 1.

May I know why the following code does not work?

```
train_copy <- train[c(2:11)]
train_copy <- scale(train_copy)
train[c(2:11)] <- train_copy
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You've missed a dimension: `train_copy <- train[, 2:11]` and `train[, 2:11] <- train_copy`.

Comment: If `train` is a dataframe it should work (assuming he variables are all numeric). Can you share the output of `str(train)` please.If it is a matrix, than you need the to use the comment above.

Comment: Problem solved. the output of str(train_copy) after scaling is in numeric. I used train_copy <- as.data.frame(scale(train_copy)) and it works! Thank you so much!